# upload multiple image with hasMany relation

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

hello I am using laravel 8, I have a product and image table and i want to be able to upload 3 images with each product

**product model**

```php
class Product extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use HasFactory, AuditableTrait;

    const FILLABLE = ['name','price','description'];
    protected $fillable = ['name','price','description'];
    
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Image::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

**product migration**

```php
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->double('price');
            $table->text('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

**image model**

```php
class Image extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['product_id', 'file_path'];

}
```

**image migration**

```php
class CreateImagesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained();
            $table->string('file_path');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('images');
    }
}
```

and this the methode inside my product controller that supposed to store data

```php
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $product = Product::create($request->only('name','price','description'));
        if($images = $request->file('images')){
            foreach($images as $image){
                $image->store('product','public');
                Image::create([
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'file_path' => $image->hashName()
                ]); 
            }
        }
        return $product;
    }
```

when i test this method with postman i was able to store data into product
but the image table stays empty it did not receive any data
any help!

Comment: Have you tried logging? Are the images saved?

Comment: @KevinBui no when i `dd($request->all()` it shows me all information about product and image, when i manually add data with `return Product::with('images')->get();` in the get request i get the product with image related to it

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $product = Product::create($request->only('name','price','description'));
        if($images = $request->file('images')){
            foreach($images as $image){
                $image->store('product','public');
                $product->images()->create([
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'file_path' => $image->hashName()
                ]); 
            }
        }
        return $product;
    }
```

Comment: the image upload did not go through

Comment: Oh sorry I have missed images() relation call. Please try the updated code now

Comment: $product->images()->create([
                    'product_id' => $product->id,
                    'file_path' => $image->hashName()
                ]);

Comment: it did not get uploaded can you reach me from this to explain more and see full [code](https://github.com/jagarkin/test-api), it's been two days now

Comment: Please replace the line 48 of ProductController.php with this line: `$product->images()->create([`